# Groupby more than1 columns and then average over another column

Tags: python-3.x, average, pandas-groupby

I have the follow dataset:

```
     cod           date              value 
0   1O8        2015-01-01 00:00:00    2.1
1   1O8        2015-01-01 01:00:00    2.3
2   1O8        2015-01-01 02:00:00    3.5
3   1O8        2015-01-01 03:00:00    4.5
4   1O8        2015-01-01 04:00:00    4.4
5   1O8        2015-01-01 05:00:00    3.2
6   1O9        2015-01-01 00:00:00    1.4
7   1O9        2015-01-01 01:00:00    8.6
8   1O9        2015-01-01 02:00:00    3.3
10  1O9        2015-01-01 03:00:00    1.5
11  1O9        2015-01-01 04:00:00    2.4
12  1O9        2015-01-01 05:00:00    7.2
```

I want to aggregate by cod and date(month) and do an average of the value, like this:

```
                  value     
cod  date
1O8  2015-01-01    3.3
1O9  2015-01-01    4.9
```

My data have the follow type: dtypes: `object(1), datetime64[ns](1), float64(1)`

I try to use `.groupby()` function to aggegrate:

```
df.groupby(['cod', 'date', 'value']).size().reset_index().groupby('value').mean()
```

But did'nt produce the correct result

Answer (score 1):

using a [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Grouper.html)

```
df.groupby(["cod", pd.Grouper(key="date", freq="MS")]).mean()
```

Extra info on [pbpython.com](http://pbpython.com/pandas-grouper-agg.html)

Comment: This function generate this error: `IndexError: index 43462904 is out of bounds for size 43462904`. As usual?

Comment: It works for this small sample, so has probably something to do with the values in row `43462904 `